# asymptotic distribution of the maximum of partial sums of iid binary random variables (Bernoulli)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion

I've encountered a problem when using the random walk to approximate a Brownian motion:

Consider a sequence of iid random variable ${X_{i}}\ $ where $i=1,2,...\ $ with binary outcomes such that:
$X_{i}=1$ with probability $p$, and $X_{i}=-1$ with $1-p$.

Define the partial sums as $Y_{n}=X_{1}+X_{2}+...+X_{n}$.

And the maximum as $Z_{n}=\max_{1\leq i \leq n} {Y_{i}}$

Let $a\ $ be a positive number. The problem is to find the value of

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Pr\lbrace Z_{n}\geq a\rbrace
$$

I tried to consider an example where $a=0.5$, then
$$
\Pr\{Z_{1}\geq0.5\}=p
$$
$$
\Pr\{Z_{2}\geq0.5\}=\Pr\{\max_{i=1,2}Y_{i}\geq0.5\}=\Pr\{\max\{X_{1},X_{1}+X_2\}\geq0.5\}
$$
$$
=1-\Pr\{X_1<0.5, X_1+X_2<0.5\}=1-\Pr\{X_1+X_2<0.5\mid X_1<0.5\}\Pr\{X_1<0.5\}
$$
$$
=1-1*(1-p)=p
$$
and
$$
\Pr\{Z_3\geq0.5\}=1-\Pr\{X_1<0.5, X_1+X_2<0.5, X_1+X_2+X_3<0.5\}
$$
but it seems complicated, according to the answer for a similar question: [Distribution of maximum of partial sums of independent random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68553/distribution-of-maximum-of-partial-sums-of-independent-random-variables), Markov property doesn't hold here.
And the result is:
$$
\Pr\{Z_3\geq0.5\}=p^2+p-p^3
$$

So is there a closed-form expression for this binary case? Many thanks!

Comment: For the closed-form, I don't know but I'd doubt. In any case, you don't need it to solve your problem.